# How to fix an expected an indented block error?

Tags: python

I was trying to create a BMI calculator in Python, but when I run the program, it says: 'IndentationError: expected an indented block'. It says that the error is in line 7, but what did I wrong? I'm using Python 3.5.1

```
print ('Give your weight in kg: ')
weight_kg = float(raw_input())
print ('Give your length in meters: ')
length_meters = float(raw_input())
bmi = weight_kg / (length_meters * length_meters)
if bmi <= 18.5:
print ('Your BMI is'), bmi, ('what means that you have got underweight')
elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi <= 25:
print ('Your BMI is'), bmi, ('what means that you have got a normal weight')
elif bmi > 25 and bmi < 30:
print ('Your BMI is'), bmi, 'what means that you have got overweight')
elif bmi >= 30:
print ('Your BMI is'), bmi, ('what means that you have got obese')
```

Comment: after opening any block give 4 spaces to indent that block, try it.

Comment: You fix the indented block error by fixing the indented block.  Python relies on indentation to describe which code is in which blocks.  If you had an `if` inside of an `if` with no indentation and said `elif`, how would Python know which `if` the `elif` was for?  How would Python know if the second `if` is inside or outside of the first `if`?  Indentation makes it clear what you mean.

Comment: A basic tutorial might spare you some pain. The [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) has this to say about indentation: "indentation is Python’s way of grouping statements. [...] Note that each line within a basic block must be indented by the same amount."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, subordinate statements are identified by their indentation level, in contrast to curly braces or begin/end keywords used by some other languages.  As such, proper indentation in Python is more than mere stylistic convention, but is in fact required for correct functionality.  In your case, you need to indent your subordinate statements.  Try the following:

```
print ('Give your weight in kg: ')
weight_kg = float(input())
print ('Give your length in meters: ')
length_meters = float(input())
bmi = weight_kg / (length_meters * length_meters)
if bmi <= 18.5:
    print ('Your BMI is', bmi, 'what means that you have got underweight')
elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi <= 25:
    print ('Your BMI is', bmi, 'what means that you have got a normal weight')
elif bmi > 25 and bmi < 30:
    print ('Your BMI is', bmi, 'what means that you have got overweight')
elif bmi >= 30:
    print ('Your BMI is', bmi, 'what means that you have got obese')
```

Comment: Your editing of his strings has caused a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but now I got another problem: the program can run, but it says that it doesn't know what float(raw_input()) means. I changed the float in int, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: @zondo Thanks, I hadn't actually tried to load it.  The original strings had `'...you've...'` in them, which caused the syntax errors.  I see now that the post has been changed to use `'...you have...'` instead, so I edited my answer accodingly.

Comment: @L.Peters: Does it have a `NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`?  If it does, you are using Python3 and should use `input()` instead.

Comment: Sorry, there were some additional syntax errors in the original post which I've corrected as well.  Are you still having problems?  This should work in Python 2 now.

Comment: @zondo agreed, for Python 3 `raw_input` needs to be changed.

Comment: I changed my answer to use `input()` in place of `raw_input()`.  In this instance, it should work in both Python 2 and Python 3.  Let me know if you experience any more problems.

Comment: @zondo thanks! The error is fixed, I was still thinking about the Python 2.7 version. Now it says something that it can't make the calculation, but my  main problem is fixed, thanks!